# Use scrollTo, "next" section without repeating code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to work out the best way to do this without replicating lots of code.

I have a small "scroll" button and I'd like to use `scrollTo` and this button to scroll to the next `section`.

I understand that I can use scrollTo with a absolutely defined div/HTML container as such:

```
$('#scrolly').click(function() {
   $.scrollTo($('#myDiv'), 500);
});
```

The issue with this is that with multiple divs to scroll to, I've have to replicate this script every time with each div name. E.g

```
$('#scrolly2').click(function() {
   $.scrollTo($('#myDiv2'), 500);
});
```

Instead, is there a way that I can say each `scrolly` icon should scrollTo the NEXT div in the DOM from it's current one?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/DQBQs/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrolling down to next element via keypress & scrollTo plugin - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146748/scrolling-down-to-next-element-via-keypress-scrollto-plugin-jquery)

Comment: jQuery provides a next() function. http://api.jquery.com/next/ 

You can use that to get the next div.

Comment: If all the elements have something in common, like a `class` or their ID starts/ends/contains something shared, you can play with the selector. To know where to scroll to (which element) you can add a `data` attribute to the clicked element.

Comment: Your question is more about logic than coding issues/difficulties.

Comment: @melanciaUK are you suggesting some sort of var which stores a number, and then use that to create the div name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in the next section

```
$('.scroller').click(function (){
    var next = $(this).closest('section').next('section');
    $(document).scrollTo(next, 400);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DQBQs/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this was just the kind of answer I was looking for. I wasn't aware of `.closest`, thanks.

Comment: Any idea why this now won't work once implemented into my site? http://francesca-designed.me/negozio/ I have also moved my actual HTML across into a JSFiddle and it works there OK. http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/3cfXS/

Comment: @Francesca - You put the javascript outside document.ready, and before the DOM elements are loaded.

Comment: even when I put it inside a document.ready parentheses and at the bottom of the page, it doesn't work. francesca-designed.me/negozio

Comment: Ah, you're missing the plugin, `scrollTo` is not part of jQuery nor jQuery UI, it's a plugin -> **https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo**

Comment: Ah thanks! I thought it was included. How comes it works in JSFiddle?

Comment: I included it in the fiddle !